# select packages related to some program in apt archive

Tags: installation, apt, deb, cache, archive

Suppose that I have installed a program "someProgram". Now, I want to select the `.deb` packages that were downloaded into `/var/cache/apt/archive` folder.

How can I select the packages related to someProgram in `/var/cache/apt/archive` ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you mean by 'related to', however, if you do:

```
aptitude show some-package-name
```

This will show you the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type as

```
ls /var/cache/apt/archives | grep <package_name>
```

for example

```
jai@frank-Jai:~$ ls /var/cache/apt/archives/ | grep vlc
libvlc5_2.0.8-0ubuntu0.13.04.1_i386.deb
libvlccore5_2.0.8-0ubuntu0.13.04.1_i386.deb
vlc_2.0.8-0ubuntu0.13.04.1_i386.deb
vlc-data_2.0.8-0ubuntu0.13.04.1_all.deb
vlc-nox_2.0.8-0ubuntu0.13.04.1_i386.deb
vlc-plugin-notify_2.0.8-0ubuntu0.13.04.1_i386.deb
vlc-plugin-pulse_2.0.8-0ubuntu0.13.04.1_i386.deb
jai@frank-Jai:~$
```

Comment: It is not a complete list of downloaded .deb files (dependencies).